# Wix: Autogenerated WXS still referencing deleted files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wix

We have removed some PNG image files from a solution but the installer is still including them in the autogenerated WXS file.

The files don't exist in the file system and are no longer referenced in the solution as far as I can see.

Where does the tool set get these references from?

I've tried a clean and rebuild but the wxs keeps getting regenerated with these missing files.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: how are you auto genereating the wxs?

Comment: Well that's what I'm trying to understand. I have a bunch of errors saying the system cannot find the file whatever.png. All the errors seem to originate in Website.Autogenerated.wxs. I've tried editing the file manually to remove those components and I've tried physically removing the whole file and I still get the same errors. It's like an old version of that file is cached somewhere but I can't find it.

Comment: Incidentally, I physically removed the file to try and force a full auto-generation but that didn't happen. The file did not get recreated and yet I got those same errors again.

Comment: woops I put a comment on the wrong issue.

Comment: Can you try to get a minimal code block that reproduces the issue or can give a better idea of how it's getting generated? Also can you add the exact error messages you're getting? Edit your original question with this additional info if you can :)

Comment: Check you `Include`s in your .wixproj to see which wxs (and other references) is your project using to confirm that you are indeed editing the right Website.Autogenerated.wxs. Clean you intermediate files just in case, for example the obj, bin folder and maybe the reference to those files might not be in the autogenerated file but somewhere in the project. Do a text search on the whole folder (use notepad++, or vscode) and search for the removed files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I had some bad references in the main project which were preventing the Website.Autogenerated.wxs from getting regenerated so it kept using an older version. Where the hell it was being cached, I have no idea, but fixing my project solved the problem.

Thanks again all for your help.